# no funciona el codigo, despues class FormularioClientes: global texBoxIdde me tira error en la palabra global

Tags: python

import tkinter as tk

#importo modulos restantes de tkinter
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

from clientes import *

from conexion import *

class FormularioClientes:
global texBoxId
texBoxId = None

global texBoxNombres
texBoxNombres = None

global texBoxApellidos
texBoxApellidos = None

global combo
combo = None

global base
base = None

global groupBox
groupBox = None

global tree
tree = None

```
#creo objeto de interfaz
```

def Formulario():
global texBoxId
global texBoxNombres
global texBoxApellidos
global combo
global base
global groupBox
global tree

```
    try:
        base = Tk()
        base.geometry("1200x300") #creacion de ventana con dimensiones
        base.title("Formulario de Muestra") #titulo de la ventana
        
        #Primer ventana del lado izquierdo
        groupBox = LabelFrame(base,text="Datos del personal",padx=5,pady=5) #caja contenedora de datos
        groupBox.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10) #primer columna

        labelId=Label(groupBox,text="Id:",width=13,font=("arial",12)).grid(row=0,column=0)
        texBoxId = Entry(groupBox) #creo campo para introducir texto
        texBoxId.grid(row=0,column=1)
        
        labelNombres=Label(groupBox,text="Nombres:",width=13,font=("arial",12)).grid(row=1,column=0)
        texBoxNombres = Entry(groupBox) #creo campo para introducir texto
        texBoxNombres.grid(row=1,column=1)
        
        labelApellidos=Label(groupBox,text="Apellidos:",width=13,font=("arial",12)).grid(row=2,column=0)
        texBoxApellidos = Entry(groupBox) #creo campo para introducir texto
        texBoxApellidos.grid(row=2,column=1)

        labelSexo=Label(groupBox,text="Sexo:",width=13,font=("arial",12)).grid(row=3,column=0)
        seleccionsexo = tk.StringVar() #desplegable
        combo = ttk.Combobox(groupBox,values=["Masculino","Femenino"],textvariable=seleccionsexo)
        combo.grid(row=3,column=1)
        seleccionsexo.set("Masculino")

        #creacion de botones
        Button(groupBox,text="Guardar",width=10, command=guardarRegistros).grid(row=4,column=0)
        Button(groupBox,text="Modificar",width=10).grid(row=4,column=1)
        Button(groupBox,text="Eliminar",width=10).grid(row=4,column=2)

        #Segunda ventana lado derecho
        groupBox = LabelFrame(base, text="Lista del personal", padx=5,pady=5,)
        groupBox.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
        #Crear treview

        #Configurar las columnas
        #Primer en la variable tree invoco la funcion de tkk, despues donde lo quiero,despues las columnas y lo que contienen, que se muestren y pot ultimo distacia.
        tree = ttk.Treeview(groupBox,columns=("Id","Nombres","Apellidos","Sexo"),show="headings",height=5,)
        tree.column("# 1", anchor=CENTER)
        tree.heading("# 1", text="Id")

        tree.column("# 2", anchor=CENTER)
        tree.heading("# 2", text="Nombres")

        tree.column("# 3", anchor=CENTER)
        tree.heading("# 3", text="Apellidos")

        tree.column("# 4", anchor=CENTER)
        tree.heading("# 4", text="Sexo")

        tree.pack()
        



        base.mainloop() #cierra la ventana correctamente
        


    except ValueError as error:
        print("error al mostrar la interfaz, error: {}".format(error))
```

def guardarRegistros():

```
global texBoxNombres, texBoxApellidos, combo, groupBox
        
try:
            #verifico si los widgets(botones, etc) estan inicializados
    if texBoxNombres is None or texBoxApellidos is None or combo is None:
        print("Los widgets no estan inicializados")
        return
            
    nombres = texBoxNombres.get()
    apellidos = texBoxApellidos.get()
    sexo = combo.get()

    CClientes.ingresarClientes(nombres, apellidos, sexo)
    messagebox.showinfo("Informacion", "Los datos fueron guardados")
        
    #Limpio los campos
        
    texBoxNombres.delete(0, END)
    texBoxApellidos.delete(0, END)
        
    
except ValueError as error:
        print("Error al ingresar los datos {}".format(error))
```

Formulario()

Comment: ¿Está realmente mal indentado tu código? ¿O solo lo _copypasteaste_ incorrectamente?